# Find out the current size of Collection and size of each module inside a collection of a TFS repository

Tags: collections, tfs, module, size

I am using Team Foundation Server in my project. The requirement is to find out the

- Current size of Collection
- Current size of each module inside a Collection

Comment: didn't get you. what you need exactly ?

Comment: 1. Assume that you mean the TFS collection, which includes all code, work items, test results, work item attachments. etc. 2. What do you mean by "module"?

Comment: -->http://my.tfs.local:8080/tfs/Migration/TFStoGIT
-->http://my.tfs.local:8080/tfs/ is URL for my repository
-->Migration is my Collection
-->TFStoGIT is my Module
Module is similar to a project

Comment: Why do you want to query the size of database?

Answer (score 1):

Each team project collection has a database. Each database stores the data for the team projects (version control, builds, and work items) in that collection.

[image]

You can run reports for the collection database to check collection size and table size. But we always not recommend to deal with database directly, make sure you have full backup of database before any operation on it.

[image]

Comment: But where does this database reside?

Comment: In the SQL Server on your Data Tier machine.